# How to pass argument in Expect through the command line in a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, expect

I am passing argument in Expect through the command line in a shell script.

I tried this

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
    
set arg1 [lindex $argv 0]
    
spawn lockdis -p
expect "password:" {send "$arg1\r"}
expect "password:" {send "$arg1\r"}
expect "$ "
```

But it's not working. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

If you want to read from arguments, you can achieve this simply by

```
set username [lindex $argv 0];
set password [lindex $argv 1];
```

And print it

```
send_user "$username $password"
```

That script will print

```
$ ./test.exp user1 pass1
user1 pass1
```

You can use Debug mode

```
$ ./test.exp -d user1 pass1
```

Comment: While this works, be careful using it as your process will appear with the arguments, username and password, when doing something like "ps aux"

Comment: can we loop the argument list and put them in array?

Comment: That's why you should pass it a file where your username and password are kept privately.

Answer (score 10):

A better way might be this:

```
lassign $argv arg1 arg2 arg3
```

However, your method should work as well. Check that `arg1` is retrieved. For example, with `send_user "arg1: $arg1\n"`.

Comment: The code above is for TCL which `expect` is using, and doesn't make sense for Bash.

Answer (score 8):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set username [lindex $argv 0]
set password [lindex $argv 1]
log_file -a "/tmp/expect.log"
set timeout 600
spawn /anyscript.sh
expect "username: " { send "$username\r" }
expect "password: " { send "$password\r" }
interact
```

Answer (score 7):

I like the answer provided with [this guide](http://npg.dl.ac.uk/MIDAS/manual/ActiveTcl8.5.7.0.290198-html/expect4win/ex_tut.html).

It creates a parse argument process.

```
#process to parse command line arguments into OPTS array
proc parseargs {argc argv} {
    global OPTS
    foreach {key val} $argv {
        switch -exact -- $key {
            "-username"   { set OPTS(username)   $val }
            "-password"   { set OPTS(password)   $val }
        }
    }
}
parseargs $argc $argv
#print out parsed username and password arguments
puts -nonewline "username: $OPTS(username) password: $OPTS(password)"
```

The above is just a snippet. It's important to read through the guide in full and add sufficient user argument checks.

Comment: I like argument checking all the time

Answer (score -2):

Note, sometimes argv 0 is the name of the script you are calling. So if you run it that way, argv 0 doesn't work.

For me I run

```
expect script.exp  password
```

That makes argv 1 = password and argv 0 = script.exp.

Answer (score -4):

Arguments with spaces are fine, assuming the argument you want is the first after the script name (`$0` is script name, `$1` is the first argument, etc.)

Make sure you use `"$ARG"`, ***not*** `$ARG` as it will ***not*** include the whitespace, but break them up into individual arguments. Do this in your Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

ARG="$1"
echo WORD FROM BASH IS: "$ARG" #test for debugging

expect -d exp.expect "$ARG"

exit 0
```

Also, as [the first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059682/how-to-pass-argument-in-expect-through-the-command-line-in-a-shell-script/17060172#17060172) states, use debug mode, (the `-d` flag). It will output your `argv` variables as Expect sees them and should show you what is going on.

Comment: The expect script is missing

Comment: It isn’t, “missing” it works the same way for any expect script that would be called via bash. Though in this example it would need to be called, “exp.expect.” There was no need for a downvote, my answer explains how to handle what was in question.

Comment: ok, I `expect`ed the content of your script which references the parameters from outside as the others showed in their examples.