# How to use command line switches in expect?

Tags: expect

I want to know how to use switches at the command line in `expect` just like `getopts` in `bash` scripts.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

See [How to pass argument in expect through command line in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059682/how-to-pass-argument-in-expect-through-command-line-in-shell-script) and http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html (Usage section).

Update: Expect is based on Tcl, and the usual method in Tcl to parse optional arguments from the command line as in `getopts` is [the cmdline library package](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/cmdline/cmdline.html).  This is part of [tcllib](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1246), so you might need to install that if it's not already on your system.

Comment: Well this is similar to normal args but not switches. I need something like you give switches with/without args to `ls`(like `ls -l` `grep -c5 xx`) or any other `shell` commands. One way is to do using passing them at the command line and use regular expressions. Instead is there method just like `getopts` in `bash`?

Comment: That's what the `cmdline` package does. Docs: http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/cmdline/cmdline.html